# Latency in windowed key emission during Realtime processing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Below is Kafka streaming topology which emits Realtime aggregated key and its value. Observing latency when record are getting emitted. Emission happens in secs instead of instant once new record arrives which is breaching SLA for client.

Can you suggest on tuning of immediate key emission?

```java
KTable<Windowed<String>, JsonNode> aggregateTable =
  transactions
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(windowDuration)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(windowGraceDuration)))
    .aggregate(() -> new AggregationService().initialize(),
               (key, transaction, previousStats) -> new AggregationService().build(key, transaction, previousStats, runByUnit),
               Materialized.<String, JsonNode, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(statStoreName).withRetention(Duration.ofSeconds((windowDuration + windowGraceDuration + windowRetentionDuration)))
                                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                                                .withValueSerde(jsonSerde)));
aggregateTable.toStream().toTopic(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your topology includes an aggregation over a window which means the data will be collected within that window period and wait before throwing out a result.

In addition, you have set a grace period for late arrivals of data.

Therefore, your minimal latency will be the time: `windowDuration + windowGraceDuration`. If you want to decrease that time you would have to decrease these two values but that would significantly change your overall results.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your  reply, Above topology does emit intermittent aggregation until window is closed as i did not use suppress feature which hold recent key and its value and emits after windowDuration + windowGraceDuration. Problem I am facing is topology taking time to emit final result  in sec's  instead of millsec which is not anticipated. I received transaction say 10/9/2020 5.56.01, it does aggregation but emits final results at 10/9/2020 5.56.05 meaning after 4 secs

Comment: Try to disable record caching: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html